# connecting to SFTP is not working form the command line

Tags: php, command-line, sftp

I am trying to read a file from SFTP. I am able to connect to the server read information when I run the URL via browser.

But when I run this command from the command line I get many errors

This is the error that I get

> C:\Users\test>php -f C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php
>       PHP Warning:  require(../classes/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such
>        file or directory in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on line 17
>
> Warning: require(../classes/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>        or directory in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on line 17
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../classes/connection.php'
>        (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on li
>       ne 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../classes/connection.php' (inc
>       lude_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on line 17

This is how I connect to the server using SFTP.

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

Another weird thing is that another file using similar code works with no issues!

I am not sure what could be causing this issue

**EDITED**

Here is my entire code after the edit

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);
    ini_set('user_ini.cache_ttl', 900);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $today = strtotime( "-25 day" );


    $remote_file = '/per/Data_'. date('Ymd', $today ) . '.csv'; 

    //set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    include(__DIR__ . '/Net/SFTP.php');
    //include "phpseclib.php";

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('IPADDRESS');
    if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    if(empty($sftp->size($remote_file))){
        exit('File Not Found - ' . $remote_file);
    }

    $csv = $sftp->get($remote_file);

    $handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fputs($handle, $csv);
    rewind($handle);
    $data = array();

    while ($csv_row = fgetcsv($handle) ) {
        $data[] = $csv_row; 
    }

    fclose($handle);



require realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') . '/classes/connection.php';
```

Comment: error seems clear to me

Comment: @Dagon I forgot to copy the include line from my original code. Please check my updated question

Comment: `similar code !== same code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `__DIR__` in your `require` in order to require your files properly:

```
require(__DIR__ . "../classes/connection.php")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. here is the error now `Warning: require(C:\phpsites\dp_in../classes/connection.php): failed to
 open stream: No such file or directory in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\phpsites\dp_in
../classes/connection.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\phpsites\dp_in\IN_sales.php on line 17`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues...

1) You need to define your includes path so that the `require` works

2) Your connection is probably failing because of #1 (missing credentials from included file)

Comment: please check my updated question as I am already requiring the file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

I added this code to the top one my file

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

This changes the working directory to the running file path.